# PHP: How to make a get-request correctly?

Tags: php, get, request

On the site, I connect a banner.
I need to see what the banner looks like before everyone sees it.
To do this, I write a condition to show a banner using a get request:

```
<?php

if (($today1 >= $day25mar21) || (!empty($_GET['getSlide_with_date_from25mar21'])) || ($_GET["date_from"] == "'25mar21'")) {
        require_once 'slides/slide-1__from-25-mar-21__v1.php';
    }

?>
```

But the banner is not shown.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What URL are you visiting to test with?

Comment: Hello, thank you, 
http://www.somesite.com/?date_from="25mar21"
or
http://www.somesite.com/?getSlide_with_date_from25mar21="123"

Comment: If, above your `if` statement, you write `print_r($_GET)` what comes out?

Comment: why not dev locally? then you wont need it and you can properly test if `$today1 >= $day25mar21` is going to work

Comment: Thank you,
That's just the point, locally such a get-request works. Before the date of publication of the banner, when entering a get request, I can see the banner on the site.
But when I publish such a "code" on the site, the get request gives nothing.

The expression $ today1> = $ day25mar21 is needed to determine from what date the banner should be shown. And on what date to stop showing the banner.
It completely looks like this:
($ today1> = $ day25mar21) && ($ today1 <$ day30mar21)

Comment: The variable $ today1 has the current timestamp.
The variable $ day25mar21 has a timestamp of March 25th.
<? php
$ day25mar21 = mktime (0, 0, 0, 3, 25, 2021);
?>

The variable $ day30mar21 has a timestamp of March 30th.
<? php
$ day30mar21 = mktime (0, 0, 0, 3, 30, 2021);
?>

That is, I am showing a banner or depending on the date. Or by get-request.